# Second derivative of the Hankel function unsing sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, derivative, bessel-functions

I want to plot the second derivative of the Hankel function using Simpy. In [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[HankelH2[1%2Cz]%2Cz]) it is as easy as:

```
D[HankelH2[1,z],z]
```

This can be done analytically by using the property,

[The first derivative of the Hankel function of the second kind and first order is equal to the difference between two Hankel functions of the second kind of order zero and two, respectively, all these divided by two.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tviP.png)

But I want to learn how to derivate it directly using Sympy.
So far I've tried this:

```
from scipy.special import hankel2
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
dh2 = sp.diff(lambda x: hankel2(1,x),x)
```

The error message seems illegible to me:

> SympifyError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import sympy as sp
>         2 x = sp.Symbol('x')
>   ----> 3 dh2 = sp.diff(lambda x: hankel2(1,x),x)
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.pyc in diff(f,
>   *symbols, **kwargs)    1639     """    1640     kwargs.setdefault('evaluate', True)
>   -> 1641     return Derivative(f, *symbols, **kwargs)    1642     1643
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.pyc in
>   **new**(cls, expr, *variables, **assumptions)
>       985     def **new**(cls, expr, *variables, **assumptions):
>       986 
>   --> 987         expr = sympify(expr)
>       988 
>       989         # There are no variables, we differentiate wrt all of the free symbols
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/sympify.pyc in sympify(a,
>   locals, convert_xor, strict, rational, evaluate)
>       313         expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
>       314     except (TokenError, SyntaxError) as exc:
>   --> 315         raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
>       316 
>       317     return expr
>
> SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse u' at 0x7fdf3eca9e60>'' failed, because of exception being
>   raised: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Any clue where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use SciPy functions with SymPy. SciPy functions are numeric, whereas SymPy only works with symbolic functions (i.e., those inside of SymPy itself). Wrapping it in a `lambda` doesn't change this.

What you need to do is import `hankel2` from SymPy, and use that.

```
>>> from sympy import hankel2, symbols, diff
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> diff(hankel2(1, x), x)
hankel2(0, x)/2 - hankel2(2, x)/2
```

If you want to then plot this, you can use the `sympy.plot` function. Or, you can convert it to a numeric function using scipy with

```
l = lambdify(x, diff(hankel2(1, x), x), {'hankel2': scipy.special.hankel2})
```

and use that with a plotting library like `maptlotlib` (it looks like hankel2 is a complex function, which I don't think SymPy's `plot` handles very well right now, so you may prefer this option).